# overwrite forward animation on hover (chrome) !important not working?

Tags: html, css

I just tried to create an animation and when the user hovers over the text it will become more visible (opacity 1).
But this is not working for chrome but for firefox.

I tried to stop the animation, switch the values, etc.

(Edit: So at the start, all elements have their own animation delay, when I remove forwards the element is visible before the animation is starting. So I can't remove forwards.)

```css
.wrapper-header.element:hover {
  opacity: 1 !important;
}

.wrapper-header.element {
  opacity: 0;
  animation: dex-fade .5s forwards;
}

@keyframes dex-fade {
  from { opacity: 0; transform: translateY(15.0px); }
  to { opacity: .5; }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper-header element">
    <a class="nodec"><div>Home<div class="solid-bottom"></div></div></a>
</div>
```

The opacity still 0.5 instead of one.

Comment: remove `forwards` and make the opacity of the element 0.5 instead of 0

Comment: But the start animation is weird then. So at the start, all elements have their own animation delay, when I remove forwards the element is visible before the animation is starting.